# Error while deploying flink application on EMR

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

I am getting this error when I deploy my flink application on EMR

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/common/serialization/DeserializationSchema
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:232)
```

Although, it works fine when I deploy on a local cluster. I am using flink 1.9.0 on EMR version 5.28.0

Comment: Can You please provide some more info about Your dependencies etc ??

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be connected with multiple different things. Things to check are:

1. Version mismatch between Flink in dependencies and Flink on EMR.
2. The core dependencies of Flink should be `provided. To not cause clash with the dependencies that are available on cluster.

Answer (score 0):

What is your JDK version? Is it possible that there is a problem with the environment? I think it is very likely that the JDK version does not match